# Read one table and get rows from another table relevant to first tables row

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my conundrum, I have one customers table with an identification number column and a mooring table with an "AssociatedTo" column. The "AssociatedTo" Column would sometimes have no number because it's not assigned yet but others would have a number which would be the identification number of a customer.

I previously had a system to do this, but it was ineffective..slow.. and just horrible to look at. I need something to be able to output a table with a list of customers and as a column for one of the rows, a list of moorings assigned to the rows customer. If you could point me on my way or give an example of this code, it'd be great!

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a [`left outer join`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)), but as you haven't posted any code it's difficult to be certain what you're actually doing.

Comment: I know that joins are a good idea, but I don't know how to grab the mooring numbers if there's lots of them assigned to the customer. Is there some sort of way I could get the moorings for the customer into a separate array inside the customer array?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you have *0 or more* rows in **mooring** table associated to **customer** table.
This return 1 row for each customer row and into the **multiple** column all **m.col1** values associated to customer and separated by **comma**.

```
select c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(m.col1 SEPARATOR ',') as multiple
from customer c left join mooring m on c.ID = m.AssociatedTo
where 1
group by c.ID
```

ADD

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat for all options.

Getting the results you can use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to get the array of values.